# `simplebar` not works, how to integrate with angular

Tags: angular, angular8, simplebar

my appcomponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'simplebar';
import 'simplebar/dist/simplebar.css';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container" data-simplebar id="content">
  <div class="big-width">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Accusamus nobis similique, temporibus eaque eum vel adipisci sed harum obcaecati animi praesentium consequatur sint consectetur iure accusantium explicabo voluptate perspiciatis nemo.
  </div>
</div>
```

Looking to integrate both vertical and horizontal but not works. what should be added further?

any one help me?

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) First install npm install simplebar --save

2) In polyfills.ts add this: import 'simplebar;

3) then in main style.scss file add this: @import '~simplebar/dist/simplebar.css';

4) add data-simplebar attribute to which element you want to be scrolled with this theme.

Comment: I think adding `import 'simplebar'` in `main.ts` makes even more sense. But good answer!

Comment: hi i am new to stackbliz, i am unable to save it, just two file has to be modified, 1)  in polyfills.ts add this line - import 'simplebar'; 2) in styles.css add this line - @import '~simplebar/dist/simplebar.css';

Comment: Yes, works. but how to add further parameters to the element? say hide option?

Comment: correct this line :  Add polyfills.ts this: import 'simplebar;  as add import 'simplebar` in the existing angular `polyfills.ts`

Comment: if you want to call programmatically this scroll in a component, you have to add to component import SimpleBar from 'simplebar'; then you can call in function:ngAfterViewInit(){
  const simpleBar = new SimpleBar(elementRef.nativeElement);
}